# How to auto adjust UIView frame into another UIView Frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have `UIViewcontroler` which occupied with two component one `UITableView` of the size **Width: 120 and Height:603** of `UIViewcontroller` and another one `UIView` (detailView) related screen. (size **Width: 255 & Height: 603** )

Now I created on custom `UIView` (customView) now I want to added it on detailView, which is not fit to `UIView`

detailView Frame is half of uiviewcontroller view size.
the custom view frame is normal i.e **width 375 & height 667**

```
    -(void)loadView {

        NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:nil];
        customView = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        customView.frame = detailView.frame;
        customView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        customView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0f;
        customView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
        customView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
        customView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;            
        [detailView addObject:customView];       
    }
```

The CustomView is not auto adjusted on the detailView UIView Screen.
Your advice will be useful for understand to fix frame

@Thanks in advance

Comment: What is detailView.frame in loadVIew method ? And where are you calling this method ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri CustomView.frame = detailView.bounds;  Its help to fix the issue.  I was dumb little while. :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are setting the detailView's frame to your customView and adding the customView into your detailView.

to set the frame of your custom view please use below code:

```
    customView.frame = (CGRect){
    .origin = CGPointZero,
    .size   = detailView.frame.size
    };
```

Hope fully this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your loadView Method is written like below

```
-(void)loadView {

NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:nil];
customView = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
customView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, detailView.frame.size.width, detailView.frame.size.height);
customView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
customView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0f;
customView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
customView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
customView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[detailView addSubview:customView];
```

}